# BeautifulSoup4 extract and select data from pre style

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, tags

I want to extract all the `short_name` from this [link](https://www.bursamalaysia.com/api/v1/search/stock_list?keyword=SERBADK&lang=EN&limit=99)
I've tried already following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40228231/extracting-part-of-pre-tag-using-beautifulsoup) but it's failed. The result I got is `'None'`.

Here is my code :

```
def checkStockIdExistOrNot(stockIdNumberOrName):

    BursaStockSearchIdURL = 'https://www.bursamalaysia.com/api/v1/search/stock_list?keyword=' + str(stockIdNumberOrName) + '&lang=EN&limit=99'
    BursaStockSearchIdRequest = requests.get(str(BursaStockSearchIdURL), headers=header)
    BursaStockSearchIdParser = BeautifulSoup(BursaStockSearchIdRequest.content, 'html.parser')
    BursaSelection = BursaStockSearchIdParser.find('pre')
    print(BursaSelection)

checkStockIdExistOrNot('SERBADK')
```

My intention is to get only the `short_name` SERBADK and SERBADK-C17.
But, coz of the `'None'` value, I can't select/pick any single data out of it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As request is returning data as `json` format so you can use direct `.json` method to extract data from it!

```
import requests
res=requests.get("https://www.bursamalaysia.com/api/v1/search/stock_list?keyword=SERBADK&lang=EN&limit=99")
main_data=res.json()['data']
for i in range(len(main_data)):
    print(main_data[i]['short_name'])
```

Output:

```
SERBADK
SERBADK-C16
SERBADK-C17
SERBADK-C20
SERBADK-C21
SERBADK-C22
SERBADK-C23
SERBADK-C24
SERBADK-C25
SERBADK-C26
SERBADK-WA
```

For finding first element you can use

`main_data[0]['short_name']`

as main_data return as list you can iterate using index value

Comment: How can I print only the top one - SERBADK?

Answer (score 1):

Since the data is in JSON format, You don't need to use `BeautifulSoup` and select data from `pre` for this.

Just convert `response` to JSON using (`response.json()`) and extract the data you need.

This code will print all the `short_names`.

```
import requests

def checkStockIdExistOrNot(stockIdNumberOrName):
    url = 'https://www.bursamalaysia.com/api/v1/search/stock_list?keyword=' + str(stockIdNumberOrName) + '&lang=EN&limit=99'
    response = requests.get(url)
    info = response.json()

    for i in info['data']:
        print(i['short_name'])

checkStockIdExistOrNot('SERBADK')
```

```
SERBADK
SERBADK-C16
SERBADK-C17
SERBADK-C20
SERBADK-C21
SERBADK-C22
SERBADK-C23
SERBADK-C24
SERBADK-C25
SERBADK-C26
SERBADK-WA
```

Since you intend to get only the `short_name` SERBADK and SERBADK-C17, you could do this

```
for i in info['data']:
        if i['short_name'] in ['SERBADK', 'SERBADK-C17']:
            print(i['short_name'])
```

```
SERBADK
SERBADK-C17
```

Comment: Hey thanks! I can get the result based on your code also by     listName = []

    for i in info['data']:
        listAll = (i['short_name'])
        listName.append(listAll)
    print(listName[0]) . Appreciate them a lot!